# Why I can't find the defination of class Table from the slick offical doc?

Tags: scala, slick

I want to find the defination of class Table:

```
final class MessageTable(tag: Tag)
  extends Table[Message](tag, "message")
```

I can only find this Table by the offical doc:https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/api/index.html#slick.model.Table

```
case classTable(name: QualifiedName, columns: Seq[Column], primaryKey: Option[PrimaryKey], foreignKeys: Seq[ForeignKey], indices: Seq[Index], options: Set[TableOption[_]] = Set()) extends Product with Serializable
```

as the doc,it's a case class defined in scala.model

but when use Idea to find thd defination of the Table,use the sample code,it's defined in RelationalProfile.scala:

```
abstract class Table[T](_tableTag: Tag, _schemaName: Option[String], _tableName: String) extends AbstractTable[T](_tableTag, _schemaName, _tableName)
```

so why I can't find the defination from the offical doc?because it's abstract?but all the method in the class Table have been defined(def xxx=),so I think the class Table need not to be abstract

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why you can't find [it](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/api/index.html#slick.relational.RelationalTableComponent$Table), but as you said it's a member of `RelationalProfile`. More specifically inherited from [`RelationalTableComponent`](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/api/index.html#slick.relational.RelationalTableComponent@Table[T]extendsAbstractTable[T]). Unfortunately Slick still seems to use the very old Scaladoc layout. The newer one is a bit better, including its search function.

Comment: I recommend using the API doc hosted on javadoc.io instead. It allows you to select a slick artifact that uses the better scaladoc layout of version 2.12 and 2.13. https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.typesafe.slick/slick_2.13/latest/index.html

Comment: Thanks very much.I just search "Table" in the search box.maybe it's inside in the RelationalTableComponent so the doc do not display it directly